# Can I program a PIC 16f628a in C using Microchip's MPLAB?

Tags: c, ide, compilation, mplab

If so, is there a tutorial for doing this? I'm pulling my hair out trying to do anything with their IDE, I'd really like a straight forward example.

They have a tutorial here but it's for assembler, not C:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51281d.pdf

This link has examples written in C, but has no instructions for compiling it with the IDE:

http://burningsmell.org/pic16f628/

Any tutorials would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a C compiler for MPLab, do you have that? If you do, then you should just be able to go into the menu and select your specific PIC and compile for that chip

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version of the IDE (8.6..), how do I check if it has a C compiler that I can use?

Comment: It seems I need to use something called the HI-TECH C compiler... http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en534868#P10_502

Comment: Correct, adding the C compiler to MPLAB will allow you to program to the corresponding PIC in C